# How to test code inside GWT.runAsync() in Mockito

Tags: gwt, mockito

To get benefit of split point I wrapped my code inside a `GWT.runAsync()` block however it's causing my mockito tests to fail. Wondering how to write Mockito test for a method that has `GWT.runAsync()` block in it?

Comment: A small code sample would help.

Comment: Maybe something like: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/core/client/prefetch/RunAsyncCodeTest.java?r=10307

Comment: updated link  https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/test/com/google/gwt/core/client/prefetch/RunAsyncCodeTest.java